# MYSQL and PHP checking if IP address is already used in order to only allow viewing page once

Tags: php, mysql, ip

The coupon should only show up for IPs that haven't already viewed that type. If they do, it should echo the error page.  It is make to only allow a user to view the page once.

The IP is making it to the database, but the PHP is not working correctly to display the error page when the IP is found in the database under that type.

URL: http://muhs.trinix.co/coupon?type=czo0OiJNZW93Ijs=

```
<?PHP
if(empty($_GET['type'])){die();}
mysql_connect("localhost", "muhs_cp", "********************");
mysql_select_db("muhs_cp");
$type = mysql_real_escape_string(unserialize(base64_decode($_GET['type'])));
$randid = rand(1, 9999999999);
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$resultz = mysql_query("SELECT ip FROM coupons WHERE type = '$type' AND ip = '$ip'        LIMIT 1");

if(mysql_fetch_array($resultz) !== false){
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `coupons` (`id`, `type`, `ip`) VALUES ('$randid', '$type', '$ip')");

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM coupons WHERE type = '".mysql_real_escape_string($type)."'") or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );
$expired = $row['expired'];
$notes = $row['notes'];
$cookie = $row['cookie'];
mysql_query("UPDATE `totals` SET `number` = `number` + 1 WHERE `type` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($type)."'");
}
else{
echo "
<html>
<head>
<title>Your Coupon</title>
<link href='css/screen.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
</head>
<body id='wrapper'>
<div id='login'>
<h1>Whoops! Looks like this coupon has already been used.</h1>
<br />
<img src='../images/logo.png' />
<br />
<p>You are unable to make a coupon more than once.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>"; die();};
?>
```

UPDATE: I had an extra ! in the if statement.  Also I was able to change the code so that it only allows users to see the page once.

Comment: Use the MYSQLI or PDO library instead of MYSQL library for new code.

Comment: You use rand to insert an ID number. Your run a small risk that a duplicate will be created in that case you will have a ID which is not unique anymore. I would suggest using the build in function auto_increment (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rewrite that part:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

//if you don't want every type to be usable just once, add ip here
$resultz = mysql_query("SELECT ip FROM coupons WHERE type = '$type' AND ip = '$ip' LIMIT 1");

//better to work with num_rows here
if(mysql_num_rows($resultz)>0){
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `coupons` (`id`, `type`, `ip`) VALUES ('$randid', '$type', '$ip')");
```

Answer (score 0):

It is in this line:

```
if(mysql_fetch_array($resultz) !== false){ ...
```

If it is not supposed to return something then you should say != NULL. The way you have it will always be !== false so it will never show the page which is part of the else statement because it will never get that far.

For example,

If you want to do A only if B is in state C which for us is not having the IP in the database.

Comment: Oh thanks! I can't believe I missed that. I had it using a different variable before. Now it is all done. Do you think this is the best method to do this?

Comment: I would really have to look at it for a few minutes to tell. I can save it for later and I will post a comment here to let you know. Accept answer if your happy with it.

Comment: When I generate a new coupon, it does not allow the user to view it.  The system is scanning each row instead of just the ones with the type in the url http://muhs.trinix.co/coupon?type=czoxMzoiVGVzdGluZyBhZ2FpbiI7

Comment: yea looks like logic instead of != NULL try ==NULL because I could not access the coupon and I have never been to the site so it might be working in opposite direction